# Cython c++ module, constructor called multiple times

Tags: python, c++, cython, distutils, cythonize

I am trying to wrap my c++ class into python using Cython. I am able to create the so file and import in python, but the constructor of my c++ class is called multiple time.

This is what I have done so far.

 *file: DBReader.h*

```
#ifndef _DB_READER_H_
#define _DB_READER_H_

#include <iostream>

class DBReader
{
  public:
    DBReader();
    ~DBReader();
};

#endif /* _DB_READER_H_ */
```

*file: DBReader.cxx*

```
#include "DBReader.h"

DBReader::DBReader()
{
  std::cout << "Hello\n";
}


DBReader::~DBReader()
{

}
```

*file: dbreader.pyx*

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = DBReader.cxx

cdef extern from "DBReader.h":
    cdef cppclass DBReader:
        DBReader() except +

cdef class PyDBReader:
    cdef DBReader c_dbreader      # hold a C++ instance which we're wrapping
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.c_dbreader = DBReader()
```

*file: setup.py*

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

modules = [Extension("dbreader",
                sources=["dbreader.pyx", "../DBReader.cxx"],
                include_dirs = [".."],
                libraries = ["xxxx"],
                library_dirs = ["/usr/local/lib64"],
                language = "c++")]

setup(ext_modules = modules, cmdclass = {"build_ext" : build_ext})
```

After running `setup.py build_ext --inplace` dbreader.so file is created. And I am able to import in python. But as you can see below: Hello is printed thrice.

```
>>> import dbreader
>>> h = dbreader.PyDBReader()
Hello
Hello
Hello
>>>
```

Comment: (In future) you can inspect the C++ code that Cython generates to try to see what's happening. `cython -a` makes an annotated html page that helps link the C++ to Cython code. The constructor mechanism is slightly complex though

Comment: @DavidW will definitely try that. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this line:

```
self.c_nodegraph_dbreader = RtlNodeGraphDBReader()
```

If you just want a default-constructed instance, you've already got that, without this line.

By adding this line, you're explicitly constructing a second such instance, and then copying that over the original, and… I'm not sure exactly how that's all working, but my guess would be that the auto-generated copy constructor is calling the default constructor a third time.